# HttpWebRequest doesn't work every time

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm doing a `WebRequest` to a `Uri` but the problem is that I don't get a response every time. Sometimes I need to redo it. I would like my program to check if it got no response and if so the program will automatically recall the method for the `WebRequest` until I get a response.

In pseudocode

```
while(response == null)
{
    try it again
}
```

This is my function. The capital comment is the explanation of my issue

```
private string HttpWebRequest()
{
    string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<Siri version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.siri.org.uk/'>
  <ServiceRequest>
    <RequestTimestamp>2011-10-24T15:09:12Z</RequestTimestamp>
    <RequestorRef><USERNAME></RequestorRef>
    <StopMonitoringRequest version='1.0'>
      <RequestTimestamp>2011-10-24T15:09:12Z</RequestTimestamp>
      <MessageIdentifier>12345</MessageIdentifier>
      <MonitoringRef>020035811</MonitoringRef>
    </StopMonitoringRequest>
  </ServiceRequest>
</Siri>";

    string responseFromServer = null;

    WebRequest request = WebRequest
    .Create("http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@nextbus.mxdata.co.uk/nextbuses/1.0/1");

    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = xml;

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    dataStream.Close();


    ////////IF I GET NO RESPONSE EVERYTHING AFTER THE NEXT LINE WILL BE IGNORED
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    ///////////THIS MESSAGEBOX WILL BE IGNORED
    MessageBox.Show(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription+" Completed");



    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  The pseudocode you provide doesn't describe the actual code you provide, which itself contains comments that don't really describe what you're talking about.  As for the actual root of the problem, not receiving a response, what actually happens?  What is expected to happen?

Comment: I took the liberty to clean up your post removing comments and indending. To me, it's a bit easier to read now. If you feel that something is incorrect, do let me know. It can also be corrected via the "edit" button under your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just retry if the returned result ends up being null.. why not just do something like:

```
private void RunWebrequest()
{
     if (HttpWebRequest() == null)
     {
          RunWebrequest();
     }
     else
     {
          //continue
     }
}
```

Comment: Because the issue is not there in my code. If I get no response all the other code below 'response = request.getresponse()'will not run...

Comment: To continue on your addition below this answer... if its not returning null, try this: if (response == "") Since you said you get nothing back, it might as well be an empty string you get back. An empty string is different then null for the system. Therefore it would skip your check for null.

Comment: Did any suggestion here fix your problem by now? Let us know so your question can be marked as answered. Thank you.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I cannot test it with your solution I get following error on my function response.getResponse():
  response = request.GetResponse();
            if (response.ToString() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("failed");
            }
WebException was unhandled
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: A 401 error derrives from unauthorized access. (Credential issues) It means you did get something back though, therefore the result is not null, but unhandled. Try adding credentials, you can try this first and then play around with it: request.PreAuthenticate = true; request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; It might not be the direct answer but something tells me there is something wrong with the credentials given or handled. Another way for the request.Credentials that might be a solution is request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 401 issue with this server, instead of placing your username & password in the url as per the traveline documentation use "Credentials" instead:-

```
string travelineUrl = "http://nextbus.mxdata.co.uk/nextbuses/1.0/1";        
var travelineRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(travelineUrl);
travelineRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");
```